# Error for the line "faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.1, 5)"

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, raspberry-pi3

I am using OpenCV 3.1.0 on my Raspberry Pi 3 and am getting an error that says

> empty() in function detectMultiScale

for the line `faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.1, 5)` does anyone know the solution to this error?

Comment: I usually use it this way.                                                                       faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(
        gray,
        scaleFactor=1.1,
        minNeighbors=10,
        minSize=(50, 50)
    )   You can try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly, the problem with the .xml file you use in:

```
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
```

by https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/d7/d8b/tutorial_py_face_detection.html

Answer (score 0):

I found this on another question a while back and changing :

```
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
```

to:

```
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascade+'./haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
```

works for me perfectly

Answer (score 0):

```
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades + 'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades + 'haarcascade_eye.xml')
```